# Any reason selenium is only inputting two characters in the password form?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, input

So im just trying to open up a browser window and login to instagram through python and I cant quite get it to work! I can type in the username but then it only types two characters in the password form before switching back to the username and typing the rest of the pasword!

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari()

browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(2)

username_input = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
password_input = browser.find_element_by_name('password')

username_input.send_keys("")

password_input.send_keys("")

sleep(2)

browser.close()

Answer (score 0):

Instagram log in may be a little bit tricky. You should click the log in and password field before you send key to it. Also add some web driver wait. Try this example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(" - incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r'/your path to chrome driver/Linux/chromedriver',
        options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
username_field.click()
username_field.send_keys(user)
password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
password_field.click()
password_field.send_keys(passw)

Login = "//button[@type='submit']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Login).submit()
```